# LogOut from the application using Kentor

Tags: logout, saml-2.0, adfs2.0, kentor-authservices

In our ASP.Net project, I am using 'Kentor.AuthServices.HTTPModule' and have configured ADFS. We need to implement the logout functionality. we found the  code
 "~/AuthServices/Logout?ReturnUrl=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(Page.ResolveUrl("~/?Status=LoggedOut")) from the samples. But when we implement in our code it does not work as expected.
(we believe the session cookies are not clearing).

On logout we need to redirect to ADFS login page. 
We configured the SAML logout endpoints in ADFS and there is no  encryption certificate installed.
What could be the reason for this issue?

Please find the ADFS Bindings
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMYUh.png)
Thanks

Comment: We are using        Response.Redirect("https://win-3obaenpbsol.dc10.inapp.com/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0"); to get signout, Is that fine.

Comment: Did you realize how to do the logoutby kentor? (not calling redirect manually to ADFS)